# Show/hide template URL's in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a dynamic Array in Controller which has templates(html files) similar to below

```
 $scope.templates =
      [ { name: 'template1.html', url: 'template1.html'},
        { name: 'template2.html', url: 'template2.html'} ];
```

I have a dropdown to choose the template.
I am using ng-include in html to get these files.
The issue is:
When I have loaded template1.html and then switching to template2.html, I want to hide template1.html data and show template2.html. 
The next time, when I select template1.html, I want to hide template2.html data and show template1.html data instead of loading template1.html again.

I have tried below:
html:

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <select ng-model="template" ng-options="t.name for t in templates">
   <option value="">(blank)</option>
  </select>
  url of the template: <code>{{template.url}}</code>
  <hr/>
  <div class="slide-animate-container" ng-show="template.isHidden">
    <div  class="slide-animate" ng-include="template.url"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide-animate-container" ng-hide="template.isHidden">
    <div  class="slide-animate"></div>
  </div>
</div>

app.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.templates =
      [ { name: 'template1.html', url: 'template1.html'},
        { name: 'template2.html', url: 'template2.html'} ];
    $scope.template = $scope.templates[0];
    $scope.$watch('template',function(newValue, oldValue) {
      $scope.templates[0].isHidden = true;//will do _.each to update
      $scope.templates[1].isHidden = true;
      var xyz = $scope.template;
      xyz.isHidden = false;
    });
  }]);
```

template1.html, template2.html can be normal html files.

Please suggest.

https://plnkr.co/edit/TJKYbDrp1C1g4fQNHCi2?p=preview

Comment: Is your code not working?

Comment: @MuliYulzary hiding is successful but it is not showing up the data.

My plan is to save the data on the same screen and hide it and show it when we select the template.

Comment: Can you replicate the problem in plunker?

Comment: This can be a number of things: empty templates, wrong path... do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: @Tuco I replicated the problem but couldn't save it. I am trying to get the plunker link. https://plnkr.co/edit/TJKYbDrp1C1g4fQNHCi2?p=preview

Comment: @MuliYulzary I am not getting errors

Comment: I think the browser would cached the html, are you having performance issues?

Comment: @Tuco I checked it is not browsers issue

Comment: Ok but, the question is, how is this affecting you? Is it a performance issue, or some data not being retained after changing templates? or both?

Comment: @Tuco It is performance issue. My application has huge data in each html files. ng-include is taking time to load html file basically refreshing complete data.Hence we have to switch to ng-show/ng-hide after first time load.

Comment: I would run FIDDLER and check that the content is being called from cache (check no additional requests are being made or the request result is 304 everytime you change views) if the content is being cached then you have a rendering performance problem

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
<div class="slide-animate-container" ng-show="template.isHidden">
```

prob. meant to be:

```
<div class="slide-animate-container" ng-include="template.url" ng-show="!template.isHidden">
```

You want to **show** the div if the value of `isHidden` is false.

Comment: I am not getting template1.html data, as we are not including it. I want store data in current page don't want to move to another page.

Comment: Could you clarify?

Comment: I want to use show and hide for the templateX.html in single screen. https://plnkr.co/edit/TJKYbDrp1C1g4fQNHCi2?p=preview

My application html files are very huge that we cannot afford reload the page everytime i select file from dropdown

Comment: You're talking about issue different than the one you addressed. sadly I have to go but I'll keep track of this question.